# Is the universe eternal or temporary?

Tags: universe

Is the universe eternal or temporary? It is most importantly observed to differentiate illusion and truth.

Comment: It is eternal & unreal! that's why it is called "Maya" in Advaita

Comment: Universe is Eternal, for it is Brahman Himself. Its separateness from you (i.e. its individual existence as something different from you) is the illusion! Good question

Comment: Eternally Temporary.

Comment: Is a 'day' eternal or temporary ? It is temporary in the sense that after day, night comes. But it is eternal in the sense that after every night, day comes. so it is cyclically eternal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This illusory world is both eternal and temporary.

> ध्रुवं कश्चित्‌ सर्वं सकलमपरस्त्वध्रुवमिदं
>
> परो ध्रौव्याऽध्रौव्ये जगति गदति व्यस्तविषये।
>
> समस्तेऽप्येतस्मिन्‌ पुरमथन तैर्विस्मित इव
>
> स्तुवन्‌ जिह्रेमि त्वां न खलु ननु धृष्टा मुखरता॥ ९॥
>
> O, Destroyer Of  ( Three ) Cities Shiva, some persons call this Universe eternal ( ever lasting), others call it temporary, and yet others call it both eternal and temporary . Hence, being surprised ( perplexed ) by  these contradictory opinions on this subject, I am really becoming immodest in loquaciously praising You .

From Mahimna Strotra

The Absolute GOD is universal, omnipresent and all knowing. Nobody is able to destroy it. And Illusory world that we see which is relative is temporary upto our death or judgement day or end of our time on earth.

Also in Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta Lord said

> avyaktanadini bhutani vyaktamadhyani bharat avyaktanidhannyanaiva tatra ka paridevana
>
> This universe is always disappeared in start, appearing in middle and again disappeared in end.

Comment: You could add your own viewpoints also in these posts. Some of them are showing up in low quality posts.

Comment: But if I add viewpoints then it will become opinion based answer. So better it is from sources.

Comment: I mean you could add your own thoughts on what the scripture says. In my opinion, Viewpoint+References makes a rich answer. Only viewpoint is not allowed here. Anyways, just wanted to let you know. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Ashtavakra geetha verse 10.2 :- Look upon friends, lands, wealth,
>   houses, wives, gifts-- and all apparent good fortune-- as a passing
>   show, as a dream lasting three to five days.
>
> verse 18.1 Praise That, which is Bliss itself, which is by nature
>   stillness and light, and which by Its knowing reveals the world as a
>   dream.

Also the story of Narada asking Krishna to show him the power of Maya confirms and reiterates the fact of life being just a dream.

> Does a dream have a start? Does it have an end? All we can say is that
>   it is not real. We can dream for ever and hence it is not temporary.
>   We can wake up and end it once and for all hence it is not permanent.

Comment: can you pls provide more specific details about sources you quoted like chapter/verse numbers etc.?